# Problemas na conexão com ldap usando python ldap

Tags: python, active-directory

Sou novo no python, e estou tentando fazer uma conexão com o LDAP para verificar a existência de um usuário do Active Directory, porém, ao tentar me conectar ao ldap utilizando o seguinte trecho de código:

```
l = ldap.initialize('ldaps://%s'%ldap_server,port)
l.bind(username,password)
```

obtenho o seguinte erro:

> *** ldap.ldapobject.SimpleLDAPObject instance at 0x7f1fe040f128
>   ldaps://xxxx.teste.com - SimpleLDAPObject.set_option
>   ((17, 3), {})
>
> File "Untitled-2.py", line 20, in 
>       l = ldap.initialize('ldaps://%s'%ldap_server,port)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ldap/functions.py", line 94, in initialize
>       return LDAPObject(uri,trace_level,trace_file,trace_stack_limit)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 79, in **init**
>       self.protocol_version = ldap.VERSION3
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 125, in **setattr**
>       self.set_option(self.CLASSATTR_OPTION_MAPPING[name],value)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 664, in set_option
>       return self._ldap_call(self._l.set_option,option,invalue)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 102, in _ldap_call
>       traceback.print_stack(limit=self._trace_stack_limit,file=self._trace_file)
>
> => result:
>   None
>
> ***  ldaps://xxxx.teste.com - SimpleLDAPObject.simple_bind
>   (('user', 'pass', None, None), {})
>
> File "Untitled-2.py", line 22, in 
>       l.bind(username,password)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 231, in bind
>       return self.simple_bind(who,cred)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 216, in simple_bind
>       return self._ldap_call(self._l.simple_bind,who,cred,RequestControlTuples(serverctrls),RequestControlTuples(clientctrls))
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 102, in _ldap_call
>       traceback.print_stack(limit=self._trace_stack_limit,file=self._trace_file)
>
> => LDAPError - SERVER_DOWN: {'info': '(unknown error code)', 'desc': "Can't contact LDAP server"}
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "Untitled-2.py", line 22, in 
>       l.bind(username,password)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 231, in bind
>       return self.simple_bind(who,cred)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 216, in simple_bind
>       return self._ldap_call(self._l.simple_bind,who,cred,RequestControlTuples(serverctrls),RequestControlTuples(clientctrls))
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 106, in _ldap_call
>       result = func(*args,**kwargs)
>
> ldap.SERVER_DOWN: {'info': '(unknown error code)', 'desc': "Can't contact LDAP server"}

Como eu posso resolver este problema?

Muito Obrigado amigos!

Comment: A mensagem diz que seu script não conseguiu se conectar ao servidor LDAP. Isso pode ser por alguns motivos: endereço incorreto, firewall ou proxy na sua máquina, etc. Você consegue acessá-lo com algum visualizador LDAP? https://www.google.com/search?q=ldap+viewer&oq=ldap+viewer&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3311j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @LeonardoPessoa vou testar e torno a escrever!